# A problem on real line

Tags: real-analysis

Given any $1>p>0 \in \Bbb R$ I want to show that for a natural number $n$ there exists a natural number $m$ such that $m^p > n$. I know Archemedian property, but the power $p$ is real is creating problem.

Comment: for $p>1$ you can choose $m=n$

Comment: Elementary: Bernoulli's inequality.  Less elementary: use logarithms.  Still less elementary: prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^p = \infty$ using L'Hopital's rule.